# Merging 3 lines over and over

Tags: windows-7, merge, notepad++

I am currently compiling music charts for a radio station
and I could do with some help.

After receiving the data I am looking to merge it.

The Data received is like this.

I am using Notepad++ under windows7.

```
1-NEW-1-
BLUNDERBUSS
JACK WHITE

2-1-66-
21
ADELE

3-4-13-
BORN TO DIE
LANA DEL REY

4-3-4-
PINK FRIDAY ROMAN RELOADED
NICKI MINAJ
```

The Numbers are the chart position- Last weeks position and weeks on the chart
Followed by the Album`s Title then the artist.

I wish to get it like this if at all possible

```
1-NEW-1-BLUNDERBUSS-JACK WHITE
2-1-66-21-ADELE
3-4-13-BORN TO DIE-LANA DEL REY
4-3-4-PINK FRIDAY ROMAN RELOADED-NICKI MINAJ
```

Any ideas on how to merge the 3 lines of each data into one, any help appreciated

Comment: in what language? c#? javascript? c? perl? pascal? fortran? ...

Comment: and what have you tried? Stackoverflow requires you have a tangible problem that you have attempted and need help with (note the 'attempted' part). I would also like to say that 'String concatenation' is what you should google for in the language of your choice

Answer (score 1):

Editing my answer:

I assume the separator lines is a blank line (or with just blanks)

```
export _tab_="$(printf '\011')"
export unused_char='|'
sed -e "s/^[ ${tab}]*$/${unused_char}/" <originalfile | tr '\n' '-' | sed -e 's/--*/-/g' | tr "${unused_char}" '\n' | sed -e 's/-$//'
```

it : replace the separator lines with an unusedchar, then replaces newlines with "-", make sure we don't have "--" or "------", and then put a newline instead of the unusedchar, making the resulting things all in one separaed line again. And get rids of any remaning end of line '-'

Comment: the part changing the '--*' into '-' is optionnal, but in your example you do this (your first line ends with '-' but your expected result show no additionnal '-' between the fist and second line. There is one between the 2nd and 3rd.)

Answer (score 0):

c#

```
string finalString = "this" + " is " + "concatenation";
```

c++

```
std::string finalString = "this" << " is " << "concatenation";
```

php

```
var finalString = "this" . " is " . "concatenation";
```